# Calculate U(t) when capacitor C1 charges C2 via a resistor R

Tags: capacitor, passive-networks, calculus, equation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feFeE6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch SW1 is activated at t=10s and charge from C1 is transferred to C2.
The power supply charges continuously with 1kV 1mA.

How can I calculate the voltage U(t) at C2?

What I have tried so far:

```
If there was no C1, I could write U2(t) = V1 * (1-exp(-t/((R1+R2)*C2))
My strategy was to start with 
Q=CU
=> U2(t) = Q2(t) / C2
Say the current from C1 to C2 is Ia and 
the current from the supply to C2 is Ib
Q2(t) =Ia *t + Ib * t
now I got stuck. What is next?
U1(t) =  Q1(t) / C1
Q1(t) = Q_recharged - Q_transferred_to_C2
```

Comment: When you write \$U_2(t) = V_1 \left(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{(R_1 + R_2)C_2}} \right)\$ that is the *solution* to a certain differential equation.  Can you write the differential equation itself?  Alternately, if you're comfortable in the Laplace (s) domain, can you write *that* circuit equation?

Comment: Your assumed solution would mean that \$\small U_2=0\$ at \$\small t=\infty\$, which is not correct; even if the 1 kV source were ignored. Also,your equation for \$\small Q_2\$ would only be correct if \$\small I_a \:and\: I_b\$ were constant.

Comment: @TimWescott I tried to write the differential equations with Q, but I think it makes it more complicate. Should I rather think in U(t) than in Q(t)?

Comment: @Chu Oh you are right, both currents depend on U1 and U2 :-( So they are Ia(U1,U2) and Ib(U1,U2). Makes it even more complicate.

Comment: There's no other ways. You need to solve it using differential equations or Laplace. It's solvable, just try it, if you're stuck, then edit the question again.

Comment: Due to the R1~C1 time constant, I think you are meant to ignore these two components when the switch is initally operated and for 5 time constants thereafter. Then you can use the general solution for 1st order systems. When  C1 and C2 voltages are balanced, V1 and R1 come back into play, but the question implies that this period is not to be considered - it's only asking for the equation when there's *charge transfer between C1 and C2.*